# R Plotly Select a range with the rangeselector buttons

Tags: r, plotly, axis

I want to select a specific range with the rangeselector button of plotly.
Currently the button will only select a range before the current end date and this will change whenever I select a different range via a plot interaction.
Can I make that the button will always select the range: `as.POSIXct(c(30,80), origin= "1970-1-1")`?

```
library(plotly)

  plot_ly(x = as.POSIXct((1:100), origin= "1970-1-1")) %>%

  add_lines(y = (1:100)^2*sin((1:100))) %>%

  add_lines(y = c(0,10001), x = as.POSIXct(c(49,51), origin="1970-1-1"))%>%

  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      rangeselector = list(
        buttons = list(
          list(
            count = 50,
            label = "50 s",
            step = "second",
            stepmode = "backward")
          ))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be difficult to achieve that functionality with `rangeselector`. However, `relayout` can be your friend here -

```
library(plotly)
x <- as.POSIXct((1:100), origin= "1970-1-1")

updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    active = -1,
    type = 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = '50s',
        method = "relayout",
        args = list(list(xaxis = list(range = as.POSIXct(c(30,80), origin= "1970-1-1"))))), 
      list(
        label = 'all',
        method = "relayout",
        args = list(list(xaxis = list(range = c(min(x), max(x))))))
    )
  )
)

plot_ly(x = x) %>%

  add_lines(y = (1:100)^2*sin((1:100))) %>%

  add_lines(y = c(0,10001), x = as.POSIXct(c(49,51), origin="1970-1-1"))%>%

  layout(updatemenus = updatemenus)
```